# ReactNative: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have emebed bottom navigation tabs and have home screen on 1st tab. I want to go from login screen on Login press button to Main View having home screen on 1st tab. below is the code for Login Screen.
On `onPress={goToHome}` I get this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')
```

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { styleProps } from 'react-native-web/dist/cjs/modules/forwardedProps';
import { color } from 'react-native-reanimated';
import MainContainer from '../MainContainer';

export default function LoginScreen({ navigation }) {
  const goToHome = () => {
    navigation.navigate('MainContainer')
  }
  const [text, onChangeText] = React.useState("ExD-");
  const [password, onChangePassword] = React.useState();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        source={require('../../assets/Logo/logo.png')}
        style={{ width: 150, height: 150, paddingTop: 60 }}
      />
      <Text style={styles.loginText}>Login</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        value={text}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.inputPassword}
        onChangeText={onChangePassword}
        value={password}
        secureTextEntry={true}
      />

      <Button title='Login' onPress={goToHome} />

      <View style={styles.forgotPasswordView}>
        <TouchableOpacity underlayColor='#fff'>
          <Text style={styles.forgotPasswordText}>Forgot Password?</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View >
  )
}
```

Comment: You can destructure `navigation` only if it is a screen or else use the `useNavigation hook`

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/

Comment: `LoginScreen` must be rendered within a navigator to get access to `navigation` prop

Comment: Are you declaring your container route in App.js or index.js?https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation check the doc here, you should wrap between <NavigationContainer /> every route you need.

Comment: Can you share your root navigation file ?

Answer (score 0):

Login and MainContainer screen should be added in navigator container for using navigation prop or else use useNavigation hook

Comment: This must be a comment not an answer, as the OP did not give clear info and we are assuming